# Can Apache BalancerMember be configured to use unix domain sockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-proxy, thin

I am using the Apache Proxy balancer directive to hook up a set of thin servers (for Rails).

Like so:

```
  <Proxy balancer://thinservers>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:5000 route=thin0
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:5001 route=thin1
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:5002 route=thin2
  </Proxy>
```

However, thin can also be configured to use unix domain sockets.

So I want to be able to do something like:

```
  <Proxy balancer://thinservers>
    BalancerMember unix://tmp/thin.0.sock route=thin0
    BalancerMember unix://tmp/thin.1.sock route=thin1
    BalancerMember unix://tmp/thin.2.sock route=thin2
  </Proxy>
```

But Apache is not taking it.
Apparently nginx can do it, but I really want to use Apache.

Is there a way?

Comment: OK, it seems that no-one here knows the answer to this. Likely the answer is no. Can anyone suggest an appropriate Apache board where I can ask this question before wrapping it up?

Comment: Maybe you should try asking on serverfault.

Comment: do you get answer on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

> It provides load balancing support for
>   HTTP, FTP and AJP13 protocols

So those are the only protocols supported.

Comment: The protocol is independent of the type of socket used. Nginx proxies HTTP over Unix sockets.

Comment: Correct. Somewhere I found a sugguestion that the http://socket=%2Ftmp%2Fthin.0.sock syntax might work, however I was untable make it work nor was I able to find anything related to it in the source code. Your best bet would be to reconfigure thin to listen on TCP on localhost and use it that way.